# What is the energy loss when charging a phone battery with another battery

Tags: energy, voltage

I'm curious to find out what the energy loss is when an external battery pack charges up another battery, say one in a mobile phone.

Say my phone's battery has a capacity of 1000 mAh, and my external battery has 10,000 mAh. Can this be calculated? Is there an average energy loss that occurs or which factors does it depend on?

Comment: suggest you ask this on electronics.stackexchange.com for a thorough answer! (quick guess, you're probably looking at something on the order of 10% loss during various charging voltage conversions in the chain, in an optimal setup, in addition to any charge leaks in the source battery)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/411564/what-is-the-energy-loss-when-charging-a-phone-battery-with-another-battery